# Can't separate background for 3d image

Tags: modeling, rigging, 3d-view

I'm trying to rigg a 3d model of a Human Skeleton (PNG file) which I downloaded into my picture folder (from online) and imported it into Blender 2.8. However, I can't separate the background from the Human Skeleton. I tried to make just the background transparent, instead, it made both the background & picture model transparent. How can I make background transparent without making skeleton transparent so I can rigg Human skeleton as a model?

Comment: A .png is an image file, not a 3D model. While you can subdivide and deform a mesh that uses an image as texture, it will not be able to move limbs independently or transform in a form similar to an actual skeleton. You will need to model the actual mesh using the image as reference (and perhaps use it later as texture for the separate bone objects). If you just want the background to be transparent, then you will need to set *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend* in Eevee and connect the alpha channel to the *Alpha* socket of the *Principled BSDF* (for both Cycles and Eevee).

Comment: Thank you rjg. Can I convert the .png file to another file to make it possible to move the image limbs?

Comment: Upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (remember to pack the image from the file menu -> pack)

Comment: @Merlin I doubt that the project file will be of much use, since the issue is a very fundamental misunderstanding of what images and 3D models/meshes are.

Comment: There is no automatic magic that will make this happen unfortunately, the issue is not the image file format. An image is 2D and while you may be able to tell different objects in an image apart, the computer can't. It's just a matrix of values. There are techniques that allow computer to perform image recognition and segmentation, but that's not a feature that Blender offers. The right way to solve this is by learning 3D modelling.

Comment: There may be an easier way, if your image has an alpha channel or good contrast from the background, by loading it into Inkscape, tracing it (remove background and one color only) and import the extracted shapes into Blender.

Comment: @rjg could be 2.5D animation, so it is possible that the OP is using this as a texture

Comment: @Merlin that's not how I was reading the question, but alright.

Comment: Alternatively you could also separate each limb from the image into a separate layer in an image editor of your choice and then export each layer as an image. Import each image as plane and you can move them independently.

Comment: Thank you both -- rjg, I will use your suggestions and, try Inkscape and see how that works.